# How do I modify the values of a tuple and then return them as a tuple of a tuple?

Tags: haskell, functional-programming

I'm relatively new to programming and Haskell in general. I'm working my way through a book on the language and one of the exercises asks for the following:

Fill in the definition of the following function, using `fst` and `snd`:

```
f :: (a, b) -> (c, d) -> ((b, d), (a, c))
f = undefined
```

I'm confused what this function signature means for how the actual function should be defined, and for the order of operations in that definition. In plain language, is this saying "take a tuple, and another tuple, and then output the final mixed tuple"? Or is it saying "take a tuple, modify that tuple, and then mix that modified one with the original"?

My issue is, how do I compose the function definition so that `fst` and `snd` can make the new tuple? I know I shouldn't use a lot of brackets, but in my head I want to approach the problem by just making a single line function with brackets to simply demarcate the order of operations, like:

```
f x y = (,) ((,) snd x snd y) ((,) fst x fst y)
```

But the compiler returns an error. Am I wildly overcomplicating this? `x` and `y` are bound to `(a,b)` and `(c,d)` respectively, so shouldn't I be able to access them and return a new tuple of a tuple with the order of operations I've made with my brackets?

Comment: For a first attempt, it's rather good! Your only mistake is that `(,) snd x snd y` calls function `(,)` with four arguments: `snd`, `x`, `snd`, `y`. This is wrong, hence the type error. You need more parentheses as in `(,) (snd x) (snd y)`, or you could use the special tuple syntax `(snd x, snd y)`. Finally, while the exercise asks for using `fst` and `snd`, this is not the best practice: we usually prefer pattern matching as in Willem's answer.

Comment: why shouldn't you use a lot of brackets?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

> Am I wildly overcomplicating this?

Probably yes, the most straightforward way is probably to simply do pattern matching, like:

```
f :: (a, b) -> (c, d) -> ((b, d), (a, c))
f (a, b) (c, d) = ((b, d), (a, c))
```

while it is not a "clever trick" or something, it is readable, and easy to inspect, debug and fix.

As for the implementation, you can fix this with:

```
f x y = (,) ((,) (snd x) (snd y)) ((,) (fst x) (fst y))
```

or make this more convenient with:

```
f x y = ((snd x, snd y), (fst x, fst y))
```

but using `fst` and `snd` is typically useful if defining patterns would mean you introduce a lambda expression for example. If you can define a pattern, by using a tuple pattern you make this more readable.

For your function, there is by the way only one sensical implementation (other than using `undefined` somewhere as (sub)expression), [*Djinn*](https://www.hedonisticlearning.com/djinn/) is a tool that can (exhaustively) enumerate implementations for simply types, and this is the only one that Djinn can find.

Comment: Awesome, thank you! I did do your more straightforward way, but the use of `fst` and `snd` required in the question was confusing me. I didn't realize you could use them to state the desired tuple.